# Argo UI and RBAC - Workflow visibility by group in Namespaced install

Tags: argo-workflows

I just read a lot of posts about Argo Workflow and RBAC but couldn't find an answer to our problem.

- Argo Workflow Version : v2.12.0-rc3

We use a "namespaced" version, it is not possible to multiply the namespaces in our infrastructure ...

- User authentication with Keycloak by Groups> OK
- Each group is associated with a Kubernetes "ServiceAccount"

In Argo UI, is it possible to make certain groups only see certain workflows in a "namespaced" environment?

Answer (score 2):

SSO+RBAC is a mechanism that takes the OIDC claims and chooses which service account to use.

You can and should split this into two problems:

- Figure out how to set-up a service account with roles and role bindings to have the correct permissions.
- Figure out how to set-up the SSO+RBAC annotations on that service account so it is selected for the right users.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I see how the role and service account system works, as well as the group association from annotation.
A "Kubernetes" role only allows you to filter on types of objects, it is not possible to filter on specific annotations or on specific pod names.
The question is above all, do we have to deploy argo in "multi namespace" mode to be able to manage the workflows accessible by users (one namespaces per type / user group)? It doesn't seem possible in mono namespace mode, does it?